# How can I see specific memory value by using Hex view in IDA?

Tags: ida, hex

I'm about to use IDA pro.
I have to access to 0018F42C(EAX) by using Hex view in IDA.
Maybe I guess there is EAX value.(String is "happyy", standard input)
but Hex view shows me 0018F410 as in screen1..

[image]

If it works well, I can find string "happyy" as in screen2 
[image]

then.. how can I see 0018F42C, not 0018F410?

Comment: shortcut g and type the hex adress?